# How do I get video transparency for web?

Tags: css, html, video, transparency, alpha

I want to create a video that has transparency, but I can't have it be a Quicktime movie since it is being deployed on the web. I need something that is cross-browser compatible also.

I tried to create a video with a black background and use a blend mode in CSS to knock out the background, creating the illusion of transparency. That worked, but it also affected the art in the video that lay on top of the black background. I need a solution that will work to create transparency (alpha) on the background but not affect the rest of the content, such as seen with a QuickTime video with alpha channel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use html5 transparent video, mp4 as example, double the height, with a canvas and alpha channel.

take a look at this code:

```
        (function () {
            var outputCanvas = document.getElementById('output'),
                output = outputCanvas.getContext('2d'),
                bufferCanvas = document.getElementById('buffer'),
                buffer = bufferCanvas.getContext('2d'),
                video = document.getElementById('video'),
                width = outputCanvas.width,
                height = outputCanvas.height,
                interval;

            function processFrame() {
                buffer.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

                // this can be done without alphaData, except in Firefox which doesn't like it when image is bigger than the canvas
                var image = buffer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
                    imageData = image.data,
                    alphaData = buffer.getImageData(0, height, width, height).data;

                for (var i = 3, len = imageData.length; i < len; i = i + 4) {
                    imageData[i] = alphaData[i - 1];
                }

                output.putImageData(image, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
            }

            video.addEventListener('play', function () {
                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = setInterval(processFrame, 40)
            }, false);

            // Firefox doesn't support looping video, so we emulate it this way
            video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                video.play();
            }, false);


        })();
```

and i used this on a webpage once:

```
<div class="IntroVideo" id="canvas_output">
    <video id="video" style="display:none;" autoplay crossorigin="anonymous">
      <source src="https://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/compressed.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
     </video>
     <canvas width="920" height="1300" id="buffer" style="display: none;"></canvas>
     <canvas width="920" height="650" id="output" style="display: inline-block;"></canvas>
</div>
```

i found a transparent video example for you to try,
there is some instruction somewhere but i can't seem to find them anymore,
it's on jakearchibald.com perhaps the instruction is there too.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid it is not possible. I'm also searching, searching and searching.. But looking at your image: can't you create a CSS animation instead of video?

Comment: Thanks! I did ask some devs that I worked with and they said the same thing also. They recommended CSS too, but when you code something like this you are opening the door to testing and debugging in different browsers/devices, which I was avoiding on this project. So I ended up creating the animation in AfterEffects > Exporting it out as a PNG animation > Compressing the PNG files > And then animating these using Canvas. :-)